# How to get value of valueField of combobox in ExtJs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I create a combobox in Extjs where i am showing name of Reports and when user select any report, at back end id of report should be posted. I am not able to get id of report. I am using store to fill data in combobox.

I create a model in Extjs like

```
Ext.define('Report', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'ReportId', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'DisplayName',  type: 'string'}
    ]
});
```

Store is like

```
 var reportStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Report',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'reportlist.json'
});
```

comboBox like

```
var comboReports = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    displayField: 'DisplayName',
   valueField: 'ReportId',
   fieldLabel: 'Report',
    store: reportStore,
    queryMode: 'local',
    emptyText: 'Select a report',
    selectOnFocus: true,
    listeners: {
            select: function(combo, selection) {
                if (combo.getValue()) {
        //showData(reportId); here i want the id of seleted report to passed.

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually `combo.getValue()` returns the reportId of the selected item.
`showData(combo.getValue());` is what you need.

Comment: No it is not working.............when i try to alert value of Combo.getValue() it shows blank, i use this command Ext.Msg.alert(combo.getValue());...........it shows blank

Comment: I got my error i need to do Ext.Msg.alert(combo.getValue().toString());